# Package todonotes: Display a \todo only the \listoftodos

Tags: todonotes

I know the `todonotes` package gives me `nolist` option when calling `\todo` in order to hide a given entry from the `\listoftodos`.

However, I can't find a way in the documentation to do the opposite of this. I'd like to add an entry to the list without having something appear later on where I place the `\todo` itself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two possibilitys:

1. You can print all text in the margin completely in white  with

   ```
   \newcommand{\mytodo}[1]{%
     \todo[linecolor=white, backgroundcolor=white,bordercolor=white, textcolor=white]{#1}%
   }
   ```
2. You can fool `todonotes` and create the entry in the list of to dos by your own:

   ```
   \newcommand{\mysectodo}[1]{%
     \addcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{#1}%
   }
   ```

With the following complete code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\mytodo}[1]{% <==========================================
  \todo[linecolor=white, backgroundcolor=white,bordercolor=white, textcolor=white]{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\mysectodo}[1]{% <=======================================
  \addcontentsline{tdo}{todo}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\listoftodos

test \todo[inline]{some fixme notes about this text 1}
\blindtext
\todo{some fixme notes about this text 2}
\blindtext
\textbf{test} 
\mytodo{some fixme notes about this text 3} % <================
\textbf{test} \blindtext
\emph{test} 
\mysectodo{some fixme notes about this text 4} % <=============
\emph{test} \blindtext
\todo{some fixme notes about this text 5}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: result]

As you can  see in the image above (yellow part, marked with 3)  the `\mytodo` is not visable, but it tooks place (*could be a problem with more `\todo`s). Marked with 4 you can see the place where I added command `\mysectodo`. It needs no place in the margin, but writes the entry in the list of todos ...

Comment: Bummer! I wish this weren't so hacky, but it'll do. Thanks!